# Query EXE details on multiple server

Tags: windows

Is there a way to query the **details** for an EXE file via command line? (existing Windows tool or PS, etc)

Specifically I would like to check the **File version** and **Product version**..

The GUI equivalent would be to right-click on a EXE file and going to the **Details** tab

Answer (score 4):

Sigcheck from Sysinternals can gather most/all of this info for you.

```
> C:\Users\mfinnigan>sigcheck c:\windows\system32\acledit.dll
> 
> Sigcheck v1.92 - File version and signature viewer Copyright (C)
> 2004-2013 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
> 

> c:\windows\system32\acledit.dll:
>         Verified:       Signed
>         Signing date:   11:17 PM 7/13/2009
>         Publisher:      Microsoft Windows
>         Description:    Access Control List Editor
>         Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
>         Version:        6.1.7600.16385
>         File version:   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome! Thank you!  You think I can run this remotely on many machines?

Comment: I have no idea what your infrastructure is. Using a script, you could use PSExec or powershell remoting to run it against any arbitrary number of machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WMI datafile for this. Note that the name requires escaping the slashes.

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll" get version
```

The result looks like:

```
Version
6.1.7601.18409
```

If you're trying to get file versions to figure out installed KBs, you can also use:

```
wmic qfe list
```

WMI also has built-in ability to run on remote machines.

```
wmic /node:otherhost /user:"domain\administrator" datafile where name="C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll" get version
```

You need to use your network administrator account or the machine's local administrator account. You can also pass in the password on the command line with `/password:xyz`.